# Why does my XML code crash when its identical to other XML code that runs fine?

Tags: android, xml

I'm building my first Android program from a book. It kept crashing on an XML file. I downloaded the xml code from the book, used it and it ran fine!

When I look at them, they both look the same to me! Am I missing something about XML - are there funny empty space problems, capitals, special characters or has my XML just got an odd gremlin in it!

It's working now, but I'd like to know why.

This works!

```
<ScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:padding="10dip">
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/about_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/about_text" />
</ScrollView>
```

This doesn't work: crashes with: java.lang.runtime.exception. Binary xml file lin #1: You must supply layout_width attribute.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android.layout_width="fill_parent"
    android.layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dip">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about_content"
        android.width ="wrap_content"
        android.height ="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/about_text"/>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I guess you should watch out for missing `layout_width`-attributes. Also, you might want to show your XML to us so we can actually help you.

Comment: @Lukas - the missing xml was a SO formatting issue.

Comment: android.width is wrong. it should be android:width. This applies to the other attributes as well

Comment: Lukas - thank you for your help. (I posted the XML code - not sure why its not coming out here!)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the XML that does not work, you've got periods (`.`) in the attribute names:

```
android.layout_width
```

and

```
android.layout_height
```

which need to use colons (`:`) instead:

```
android:layout_width
```

and

```
android:layout_height
```

Answer (score 0):

for future reference their are tools that you can use to help you spot differences between supposedly identical files. [Liquid XML Editor](http://www.liquid-technologies.com/xml-editor.aspx) is one such tool but there are many more including one from Microsoft, the feature is imaginatively called xml diff ie xml difference.